# Is there a SQL syntax that will create new column by searching in 2 columns based on equal value of 3rd column in same table?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, visual-foxpro

I have 1 table, with fields named: class_code, name1, class_code1, name2, class_code2. I would like to search the value of class_code, and display it as class_code and name only, where class_code = class_code1 or class_code = class_code2. The results will display class_code and name

Is this possible using sql join syntax?

This is the table:

```
    class_code  name1     class_code1   name2     class_code2
    C0001       John      C0002         Ben       C0001
    C0002       Ren       C0001         Elizh     C0002
    C0001       Jeff      C0001         Harry     C0001
```

The output I need is:

```
    class_code        name
    C0001             Ben
    C0002             Elizh
    C0001             Jeff
    C0001             Harry
```

Comment: Your data has three class codes and two names.  I can't figure out how they are related.  And John and Ren disappear from your final results.  Why are they not included?

Comment: I would like to search if class_code = class_code1 or class_code = class_code2, if True then it will be display under Class_Code and Name

Comment: Where does Foxpro or Visual Foxpro come into play in this?

Comment: @HerbWolfe I would like to create a cursor using visual foxpro and python. I just need a sql query which is compatible to those 2 programming languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right

```
SELECT class_code, name1 
FROM tbl
WHERE class_code = class_code1 
UNION --ALL
SELECT class_code, name2
FROM tbl
WHERE class_code = class_code2
```

Comment: Yup! you got it right, Thanks. Actually I have 6 columns to compare and I think this Union is capable for six times.

Answer (score 1):

If the intention is that class_code1 and name1 should go together and class_code2 and name2 go together, you could do this with a `UNION`:

```
SELECT class_code1 AS class_code, name1 AS name FROM table
UNION
SELECT class_code2 AS class_code, name2 AS name FROM table
```